# Toggle clone on click

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label for="input-1">
<input type="checkbox" id="input-1" class="js-wpv-filter-trigger" name="wpv-known-as[]" value="input-1">input-1</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label for="input-2">
<input type="checkbox" id="input-2" class="js-wpv-filter-trigger" name="wpv-known-as[]" value="input-2">input-2</label>
</div>
<div class="show-labels">
</div>
```

When `input` is clicked, I want to copy it's parent `label` and append it to the outer `.show-labels` div. but when I click it again, I want the `label` I copied to be removed from `.show-labels` - and so forth for next `input`.

I was trying this, but didn't work:

```
$('.checkbox input').click(function() {
  var thisval = $(this).val();
  $(this).parent().addClass(thisval);
  var copy = $(this).parent().html();
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
    $(".show-labels").append(copy);
  } else {
    $(".show-labels label").hasClass(thisval).remove();
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) to clone an element and then remove when unchecked.

I also included demo to get the text only

```js
$('.checkbox input').on("change",function() {
   if($(this).is(":checked")){
    var label= $(this).closest('label').clone();
    $('.show-labels').append(label);
   }
   else{
    $(".show-labels").find('label[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').remove();
   }
});

$('.checkbox input').on("change",function() {
   if($(this).is(":checked")){
    var label= $(this).closest('label').text();
    $('.show-labelsonlytext').append("<span for="+$(this).attr("id")+">"+label+ "</span>");
   }
   else{
    $(".show-labelsonlytext").find('span[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').remove();
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label for="input-1">
<input type="checkbox" id="input-1" class="js-wpv-filter-trigger" name="wpv-known-as[]" value="input-1">input-1</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label for="input-2">
<input type="checkbox" id="input-2" class="js-wpv-filter-trigger" name="wpv-known-as[]" value="input-2">input-2</label>
</div>
with input
<div class="show-labels">
</div>
without input
<div class="show-labelsonlytext">
</div>
```

Comment: The clone function will also grab the checkbox input as well won't it? This is maybe the best answer, just use text() instead of clone() to get the text only.

Comment: @factor5 haven't heard from op to grab only text, but I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.checkbox input').click(function() {
   var copy = $(this).closest(".checkbox").find("label").html();
   var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
   if (clicks) {
     $(".show-labels").append(copy);
   } else {
     $(".show-labels label").remove();
   }
   $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.checkbox input').click(function() {
    let name = $(this).parent().attr('for');

  if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
    const item = $('<div/>').attr('data-item', name).text(name);
    $('.show-labels').append(item);
  }
  else {
    $('.show-labels div[data-item='+name+']').remove();
  }
});
```